# Retrieve meta-annotation leaf annotated element

Tags: java, java-17

I'm developing the following meta-annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface A {}
```

A use example would be:

```
@A
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface B {}

@B
public class C {}
```

Basically my problem is that I don't know how to retrieve `C` when processing the annotation. With the following processor:

```
public class AProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(A.class)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

}
```

In the `// do stuff` part I need to retrieve the `C` element, but obviously `annotatedElement` is `B`. I don't know how to obtain what I really want to process.

Comment: 1) check whether `annotatedElement` describes an annotation 2) if so, call [`roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/RoundEnvironment.html#getElementsAnnotatedWith(javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement)) with that annotation element.

Comment: @Holger surprisingly I was doing exactly that. Although you probably got there much faster than i did. Thanks for answering. I can validate your answer if you write it down